# Track number of times radio button is selected and store in text file for PHP

Tags: php

Hey this is my first post so I hope I am approaching this properly but anyway, I have a survey in which a user is presented with 8 questions and they are supposed to rate how they feel about each question by clicking the radio buttons valued from 1(strongly disagree)-5(strongly agree).  So what I need to do is record the frequency in which each radio button is selected.  Something like this:

```
$filename = "Results.txt";
$lines = file($filename); 
$q1 = $_POST['q1'];
$q2 = $_POST['q2'];
$q3 = $_POST['q3'];
$q4 = $_POST['q4'];
$q5 = $_POST['q5'];
$q6 = $_POST['q6'];
$q7 = $_POST['q7'];
$q8 = $_POST['q8'];

foreach($lines as $line) {  
        echo $line;
        if (isset($q1)){
            echo $line[$q1];
            echo $lines;
        }
    }
```

Where q represents question#.
Lastly this needs to keep a running calc and the results.txt should look something like this:
0,0,5,0,0 
0,0,0,0,0 
0,0,0,0,0 
0,0,0,0,0 
0,0,0,0,0 
0,0,0,0,0 
0,0,0,0,0 
0,0,0,0,0 
The 5 in line one means 5 users submitted a neutral radio button option (value 3).  Each line represents the tally for each question.

Please help!

Comment: do your self a favour and store the results in a db, not plain file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should answer your "question" at hand, but also yes you should move this application to use a database.

```
$filename = "Results.txt";
$lines = file($filename);

$q1 = $_POST['q1']; //stored value between 1-5
$q2 = $_POST['q2'];
$q3 = $_POST['q3'];
$q4 = $_POST['q4'];
$q5 = $_POST['q5'];
$q6 = $_POST['q6'];
$q7 = $_POST['q7'];
$q8 = $_POST['q8'];

$qN = 1;  //question number
$newLines = '';
foreach($lines as $line) {

    echo $line;

    $line = trim($line);  //remove excess newlines etc.
    $lineArr = explode(',',$line);  //split line into array by commas
    $index = ${'q'.$qN}-1; //zero based
    if (isset($lineArr[$index])){
        $lineArr[$index]++;  //add to position by one vote.
    }
    $qN++;
    $newLines .= implode(',',$lineArr) . "\n";
}

//write contents back to file.
file_put_contents($filename, $newLines);
```

Comment: also you will need an empty Result.txt to be setup already with zero values.